# Bugless Archive Library: "Archive type not supported"

Tags: c++, qt, zip

is there anyone out there with some [bugless](http://www.bugless.co.uk/products/archive/archive.html) library experience?
I downloaded the Archive library from their site and build a static library linked it with my project. I use it on windows7 with Visual Studio 2008 and Qt4.

But no matter which example code I try to compile from their site I get the message "Archive type not supported: 0".

Can anyone tell what the problem is here?

P.S. when I built the library I got a warning that common.pri was not found
and I don't know where I can set the environmental variable "ARCHIVEHOME" which I'm supposed to set.

I am happy about any help!